# Pug and Svelte each iteration not working

Tags: pug, svelte

Directly from the tutorial but just with pug as the template engine. https://svelte.dev/tutorial/each-blocks does any have experience or can point me in the direction of using svelte expressions with pug.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    let cats = [
        { id: "J---aiyznGQ", name: "Keyboard Cat" },
        { id: "z_AbfPXTKms", name: "Maru" },
        { id: "OUtn3pvWmpg", name: "Henri The Existential Cat" },
    ];
</script>

<template lang="pug">
    {#each cats as cat}
        p {cat.name}
    {/each}
</template>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

Error

```
[!] (plugin svelte) Error: src/components/Ribbon.svelte:43:1
    41|   | {@debug !{variables}}
    42| 
  > 43| {#each cats as cat}
--------^
    44|     p {cat.name}
    45| {/each}
    46| 

unexpected text "{#eac"
```

Answer (score 5):

Some of the Svelte syntax is invalid pug, which is why it's changed slightly. I guess you are using `svelte-preprocess`, if not I suggest using that for preprocessing.

The docs have info on the valid syntax: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess/blob/main/docs/preprocessing.md#pug

```
    +each('cats as cat')
        p {cat.name}
```

Comment: I was about to give up on svelte (and return to vue3), simply because I think moving back to HTML cancels out all the nice svelte's workflow. My issue was exactly the same described by Christopher. Well, my fault not to read the doc properly!. Thanks @dummdidumm (great nick BTW)